# О слове "времяпрепровождение"?

Tags: лексика, словообразование

Из словаря: ВРЕМЯПРЕПРОВОЖДЕНИЕ, ср. =Времяпровождение. Приятное в. ВРЕМЯПРОВОЖДЕНИЕ,  ср. Разг. Способ проводить время. Составить программу времяпровождения на отпуск.

Слово "времяпрепровождение" мне кажется странным и архаичным, но оно считается нейтральным по стилю. Как оно вообще появилось в языке? Мы же время проводим, а не "препроводим"? Откуда там взялась приставка ПРЕ? Пребываем во времени?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В отличие от "Грамоты", которая полагает вариант *времяпрепровождение** *нейтральным*, а **времяпровождение** - *разговорным* (http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/trudnosti?layout=item&id=36_42), в моём восприятии это ровно наоборот:

*времяпровождение* - это способ **провести** время, наполнив его чем-то полезным или приятным для себя, а *время**пре**провождение* (раз уж оно есть и даже классиками употреблялось) - способ "убить" время, буквально "**перевести**" (извести) - как переводят из пустого в порожнее, потратить хоть на что-нибудь, впустую.

Почему? Иначе нет обоснования второй приставке пре-(**пере**-). Если обратиться к исходному слову "препровождение", то в нём значение этой приставки прозрачно: "препроводить" означало "**пере**дислоцировать", ***пере**вести, со**про**водив в другое место*.

Comment: Оригинальное суждение, лично мне нравится.